# Is there a way to prevent access to a private subview via the UIView subviews property?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

An Example: I have a custom view component with a custom textfield as a subview. I would like to prevent access to the text property of the textfield outside of it's parent view so that the following cannot be done.

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {
  
  var customView: MyView!
  
  override func loadView() {
    customView = MyView()
    customView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    self.view = customView
  }
  
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    customView.subviews.map {
      ($0 as? UITextField).map {
        $0.text.map {
          print($0)
        }
      }
    }
    
  }
  
}
```

Other classes:

```
class MyView: UIView {
  
  private lazy var textField: CustomTextField = {
    let textField = CustomTextField(frame: CGRect(x: 95, y: 150, width: 200, height: 44))
    textField.backgroundColor = .white
    textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
    textField.text = "hello world!"
    return textField
  }()
  
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.addSubview(textField)
  }
  
  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("error")
  }
  
}

class CustomTextField: UITextField {
  
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
  }
  
  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("error")
  }
  
}
```

Is there a right way to proceed about this?

Comment: You cannot prevent this

Comment: Maybe you can create a UITextField sub class that overrides the text property so that it will return nothing when being read

Comment: Perhaps clarify the context why exactly have you considered it

Comment: @Kamil.S, let's say the textfield consists of some sensitive text. The aim is to prevent extraction of that text outside of the textfield's parent module.

Comment: @ArikSegal, is it possible to determine the caller of the .text property?

Comment: Best you can do is enable `.isSecureTextEntry` on the textfield. But this is insecure anyway, even if you would block access through the `.text` it can be circumvented since the actual text must be in memory. Real security comes from server side.